# akka log dead letters - why is INFO? I want it as ERROR

Tags: java, playframework, akka, actor

I am debugging some actor problem and I am not happy about way of logging dead letters. These logs are type = INFO.
I want it as ERROR, because this is important for me.
Is possible to setup it somewhere?

```
[info] a.a.EmptyLocalActorRef - Message [cz.pay.InternalOrderUpdate] without sender to Actor[akka://myapp/user/StatusUpdateActor] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach is to roll your own dead letters handling, see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/event-bus.html#dead-letters